# php if && || OR statement returning nothing ... but does separately

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm truly puzzled and need someone to shed some light on this matter for me please.

When I use those 2 statements separately they get results:

```
$ads->where('country_to', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from'])

$ads->where('country_from', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']);
```

... but once I tried to use the OR statement then I get no results, just wondering why?

```
$ads->where('country_to', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']) || $ads->where('country_from', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']);
```

I also tried this way, no results either:

```
$ads->where('country_to', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from'] || 'country_from', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks all ;-)

Comment: is it codeignitor?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a _database_ logical operation via PHP. This will not work. What class is `$ads` variable? It will probably expose methods for you to do something like `orWhere('country_from', '=', 'something')`

Comment: It sounds like you *may* need to add more brackets. Can you try `$ads->where(('country_to', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']) || ('country_from', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']));`?

Comment: Your third try, is fundamentally wrong . You are passing a method with 3 arguments, 5 parameters! It has no more room to accept it !

Comment: FusionDesign  did you checked the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using `Codeignitor`,if yes then use `orWhere()`

```
$ads->where('country_to', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']);

$ads->orwhere('country_from', '=', $_COOKIE['country_from']);// or try or_where
```

Or

```
$select = "country_to = '".$_COOKIE['country_from']."' OR country_from = '".$_COOKIE['country_from']."'";

$ads->where($select);
```

Or

```
$country_from = $_COOKIE['country_from'];

$select = "country_to = $country_from OR country_from = $country_from";

$ads->where($select);
```